# PHP ODBC Progress OpenEdge Se queda congelado

Tags: php, odbc

Buen dia a Todos,

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta sql a una base de datos progress desde php.. el resultado de la conexión me lo esta regresando como TRUE, lo que significa que si obtengo conexión a la base de datos..

mi problema es cuando hago un query con odbc_exec(), se queda cargando la pagina para siempre, como si estuviera en forever loop.. a continuación les agrego el script que estoy tratando de correr..

```
<?php    
function OpenCon()
{
$dsn = "BLUESAGE";
$usuario = "+++";
$pwd = "+++";

$conn = odbc_connect($dsn, $usuario, $pwd, SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);

return $conn;


}


$conn = OpenCon();

$sql = "SELECT stname FROM st WHERE sid = '1'";

if ($conn)
{
   $resultado = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
}
else
{
    echo "False";
}

odbc_close($conn);
```

El script lo estoy corriendo en un Windows Server con los controladores DataDirect de Progress

Como la pagina se queda cargando para siempre nunca logro obtener el error de lo que realmente este pasando..

Comment: puedes poner un var_dump($conn);exit() dentro del primer if

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\Bluesage\ventas.php:14:resource(3, odbc link)  Este es el resultado del vardump

Comment: y de  var_dump($resultado);exit()   esto lo pones abajo de $resultado = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

Comment: entonces se que queda cargando para siempre la pagina

Comment: necesito poner el exit antes del odbc_ecex() porque si lo pongo después, se queda cargando